# My for loop is not working properly however I have no idea why

Tags: javascript

So basically I'm writing a script that takes in a credit card number and outputs the provider name. (Also if im doing this in an overly complicated way advice is appreciated)

But my initial for loop to iterate over each object is not working. It will get to 3 (even though the length of the arr is 8) and then just stop...

I am dumbfounded as I have re-read the code for an hour now, checked everything I could think of but am just hitting a wall. Any help would be much appreciated!

The Code

```
var detectNetwork = function(cardNumber) {
var splitDigits = cardNumber.split('');
var length = splitDigits.length;
var first = splitDigits[0];
var second = splitDigits[1];
var firstTwo = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1];
var firstThree = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2];
var firstFour = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2] + splitDigits[3];
var firstSix = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2] + splitDigits[3] + splitDigits[4] + splitDigits[5];

var checkProvider = [
    {
        name: 'American Express',
        length: [ 15 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 34, 37 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Diner\'s Club',
        length: [ 14 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 38, 39 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Visa',
        length: [ 13, 16, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 1 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 4 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'MasterCard',
        length: [ 16 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'range',
        prefix: [ 51, 55 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Discover',
        length: [ 16, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2, 3, 4],
        prefixType: 'complexRange',
        prefix: [ 6011, [ 644, 649 ], 65 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Maestro',
        length: [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        prefixLength: [ 4 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 5018, 5020, 5038, 6304 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'China UnionPay',
        length: [ 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 3, 4, 6 ],
        prefixType: 'complexRange',
        prefix: [ [ 622126, 622925 ], [ 624, 626 ], [ 6282, 6288 ] ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Switch',
        length: [ 16, 18, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 4, 6 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 4903, 4905, 4911, 4936, 564182, 633110, 6333, 6759 ]
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < checkProvider.length; i++) {
    var currentProvider = checkProvider[i];
    var name = currentProvider.name;
    var lengthOptions = currentProvider.length;
    var prefixLengthOptions = currentProvider.prefixLength;
    var prefixType = currentProvider.prefixType;
    var prefixOptions = currentProvider.prefix;

    for(var j = 0; j < lengthOptions.length; j++) {
        var currentLength = lengthOptions[j];
        if (currentLength === length) {
            //Use first
            for (var y = 0; y < prefixLengthOptions.length; y++) {
                var currentPrefixLength = prefixLengthOptions[y];
                if(currentPrefixLength === 1) {
                    if (first === '4') {
                        if (firstFour !== 4903 && firstFour !== 4905 && firstFour !== 4911 && firstFour !== 4936) {
                            return name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currentPrefixLength === 2) {
                    if (prefixType === 'complexRange') {
                        console.log(name);
                    }
                    if (prefixType === 'simple') {
                        for (var i = 0; i < prefixOptions.length; i++) {
                            if (firstTwo === prefixOptions[i].toString()) {
                                return name;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (prefixType === 'range') {
                        var min = prefixOptions[0];
                        var max = prefixOptions[1];
                        for (var i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
                            if (firstTwo === i.toString()) {
                                return name;
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your loop has many exit points: why do you expect it to always go to the end of 8? Can you share the test data?

Comment: detectNetwork('6011123456789303') is my current test case. It should pass into the type of "complexRange" however never enters it. even when passing in an invalid string it still ends the loop at 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your test `detectNetwork('6011123456789303')` logs `Discover` if you make the following small changes to your code:

1. Replace all `var` with `const`.
2. Declare all loop index variables with `let`.  For example, `for (let i = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and explanation, I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you search Google for "javascript identify credit card provider" you will find there are free, open source libraries that have already written this sort of code for you.

Comment: Im aware, this one was for my school project so we were supposed to take our own approach :) But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that you have `var i` redeclared within the same context. [According to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), these cases do not trigger an error, however the behavior will be confusing when the values are overwritten, which is your case.

The suggestion is to rename the other `var i` to something else, and that should solve your problem.

Another option is to use `let i` [which will make the context more strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

So this code would work best (I made it so if always returns the name):

```
const detectNetwork = function(cardNumber) {
const splitDigits = cardNumber.split('');
const length = splitDigits.length;
const first = splitDigits[0];
const second = splitDigits[1];
const firstTwo = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1];
const firstThree = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2];
const firstFour = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2] + splitDigits[3];
const firstSix = splitDigits[0] + splitDigits[1] + splitDigits[2] + splitDigits[3] + splitDigits[4] + splitDigits[5];

const checkProvider = [
    {
        name: 'American Express',
        length: [ 15 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 34, 37 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Diner\'s Club',
        length: [ 14 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 38, 39 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Visa',
        length: [ 13, 16, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 1 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 4 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'MasterCard',
        length: [ 16 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2 ],
        prefixType: 'range',
        prefix: [ 51, 55 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Discover',
        length: [ 16, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 2, 3, 4],
        prefixType: 'complexRange',
        prefix: [ 6011, [ 644, 649 ], 65 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Maestro',
        length: [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        prefixLength: [ 4 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 5018, 5020, 5038, 6304 ]
    },

    {
        name: 'China UnionPay',
        length: [ 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 3, 4, 6 ],
        prefixType: 'complexRange',
        prefix: [ [ 622126, 622925 ], [ 624, 626 ], [ 6282, 6288 ] ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Switch',
        length: [ 16, 18, 19 ],
        prefixLength: [ 4, 6 ],
        prefixType: 'simple',
        prefix: [ 4903, 4905, 4911, 4936, 564182, 633110, 6333, 6759 ]
    }
];

for(let i = 0; i < checkProvider.length; i++) {
    let currentProvider = checkProvider[i];
    let name = currentProvider.name;
    let lengthOptions = currentProvider.length;
    let prefixLengthOptions = currentProvider.prefixLength;
    let prefixType = currentProvider.prefixType;
    let prefixOptions = currentProvider.prefix;

    for(let j = 0; j < lengthOptions.length; j++) {
        let currentLength = lengthOptions[j];
        if (currentLength === length) {
            //Use first
            for (let y = 0; y < prefixLengthOptions.length; y++) {
                let currentPrefixLength = prefixLengthOptions[y];
                if(currentPrefixLength === 1) {
                    if (first === '4') {
                        if (firstFour !== 4903 && firstFour !== 4905 && firstFour !== 4911 && firstFour !== 4936) {
                            return name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currentPrefixLength === 2) {
                    if (prefixType === 'complexRange') {
                        return(name);
                    }
                    if (prefixType === 'simple') {
                        for (let i = 0; i < prefixOptions.length; i++) {
                            if (firstTwo === prefixOptions[i].toString()) {
                                return name;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (prefixType === 'range') {
                        let min = prefixOptions[0];
                        let max = prefixOptions[1];
                        for (let i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
                            if (firstTwo === i.toString()) {
                                return name;
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

var n = detectNetwork('6011123456789303');
console.log(n);  // Discover
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great, thanks for helping me out I really appreciate it!